# Displace a table on javascritp

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to displace a table clicking on a button in Javascript? For instance, pushing on a HTML button to displace the table from the left-corner top to the bottom or the middle of a page? My HTML code: (I can already delete, edit and add.)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Displace Table</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="tableEdit.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="tab tab-1">
            <table id="table" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Frank</td>
                    <td>Nenjim</td>
                    <td>19</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Alex</td>
                    <td>Ferreira</td>
                    <td>23</td>
                </tr>

            </table>      

        </div>
          <button onclick="">Dislace Table</button>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="tableEdit.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, easily possible. You can add an additional class via JS, or change the table's `style` and its properties directly.

Answer (score 0):

Create CSS (Push Table to bottom left)

```
.mystyle{
      position:absolute;
      left:0px;
      bottom:10px;
 }
```

Create the **Displace function**

```
function Displace()
      {
        var element = document.getElementById("table");
        element.classList.add("mystyle");
      }
```

Add to the button

```
<button onclick="Displace()">Displace Table</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```js
function displaceTable(){
 let table = document.getElementById("table");
 table.classList.add("bottomStyle");
}
```

```css
.bottomStyle{
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Displace Table</title>
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="tableEdit.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container">
          <div id="tab tab-1">
              <table id="table" border="1">
                  <tr>
                      <th>First Name</th>
                      <th>Last Name</th>
                      <th>Age</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>Frank</td>
                      <td>Nenjim</td>
                      <td>19</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>Alex</td>
                      <td>Ferreira</td>
                      <td>23</td>
                  </tr>

              </table>      

          </div>
          <button 
            onclick="displaceTable()"
          >
            Dislace Table
          </button>
      </div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thks! Excellent!